# Why does Amazon Prime take you to the latest season of a show instead of starting you off in the beginning season?

Tags: user-expectation

Recently, I started watching "The Boys" and as I searched for it in the search bar the site it took me straight to Season 2 of the show and showed me all the episodes of Season 2. Although it said written on top "The Boys: Season 2" me being unmindful started off with Season 2 unbeknownst to me until later I learned I was watching Season 2 instead of Season 1. This UX is different from Netflix which starts you off with the beginning episode unless, it sees that you've watched some episode of a show and starts you off from where you left off.

Also I wanted to check, if I was dumb or many people had encountered the same problem. I asked 10 other people to do the same thing I did to find the show "The Boys" and play the first episode and 6 did the exact same thing I did. So I am thinking its a UX design flaw and I wanted to confirm with UX designers why haven't Amazon Prime removed it yet?

Comment: Unless you get an answer from the designer of Amazon Prime, you won't get a decent answer here. You already concluded that it's an UX flaw and given your story I think it's fair to believe so. When someone feels dumb because of a certain design, that is often a sign that there is room for improvement.

Comment: Does this relate to any problem you are trying to solve? It will be hard for anyone here to speak for them.